# Drag image from outside a canvas into canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to drag an image from outside a canvas and its copy has to be placed at the mouse point inside the canvas.

- there is an image inside canvas
- the dragged image must be on the image

My code displays both images but fails to drop it at position also gives omit symbol on being dragged even though `draggable=true` is specified.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please add your code to the question so that it's possible to reproduce and understand the problem.

Comment: We will need code to help you